# Getting Circular Dependency in angular 9 Application

Tags: angular

I created a very basic app. It contains LoginComponent, HomeComponent and an AuthService. Here is my AuthService

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, throwError, Subject, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../login/user.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { SqlRequest, SqlResponse } from './sql.service';
import { tap, exhaustMap, map, take, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MINUTE, HOUR } from '../app.module';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

interface UserData {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    token: string;
    generatedOn: string;
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService implements OnDestroy {
    user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
    private destroy$ = new Subject();
    private timer: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
        // this.autoSignIn();
    }

    signIn(username: string, password: string) {
        const request: SqlRequest = {
            queryType: 'signIn',
            tableName: 'users',
            params: {
                andWhere: { username, password }
            }
        };
        return this.http.post<SqlResponse>(environment.serverUrl, request)
            .pipe(
                takeUntil(this.destroy$),
                tap((res: SqlResponse) => {
                    if (res.status) {
                        this.handleAuthentication(res.data[0]);
                    } else {
                        throwError(res.errors);
                    }
                }));
    }

    autoSignIn() {
        const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
        if (!!userData) {
            this.handleAuthentication(userData);
        }
    }

    handleAuthentication(userData: UserData) {

        if (this.timer != null) {
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
        }

        const expirationTime = (new Date(userData.generatedOn)).getTime() + HOUR;
        const currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();

        if (expirationTime > currentTime) {
            this.user.next(new User(
                userData.id,
                userData.username,
                userData.token,
                expirationTime
            ));

            localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));

            this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                if (confirm('Your session is about to expire. Do you want to continue your work?')) {
                    this.refreshToken()
                        .subscribe((res: SqlResponse) => {
                            this.handleAuthentication(res.data[0]);
                        });
                } else {
                    this.signOut();
                }
            }, HOUR - (MINUTE * 2));
        } else {
            this.signOut();
        }


    }

    signOut() {
        localStorage.clear();
        console.log('Signing Out');
        this.user.next(null);
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }

    private refreshToken() {
        return this.user
            .pipe(
                take(1),
                map((user: User) => {
                    if (!!user) {
                        return user.token;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }),
                exhaustMap((token: string) => {
                    if (!!token) {
                        const request: SqlRequest = {
                            queryType: 'signIn',
                            tableName: 'users',
                            params: {
                                andWhere: { token }
                            }
                        };
                        return this.http
                            .post(environment.serverUrl, request)
                            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$));

                    } else {
                        return EMPTY;
                    }
                }));
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }
}
```

AppModule is also pretty basic

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

export const MINUTE = 1000 * 60;
export const HOUR = MINUTE * 60;

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And LoginComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from './../shared/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: [null, Validators.required],
      password: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    // this.authService.signIn(formValue.username, formValue.password);
  }
}
```

But I get this Circular dependency Error, I cant figure Out why is it occuring.

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
> src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\login\login.component.ts -> src\app\shared\auth.service.ts -> >src\app\app.module.ts

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
> src\app\login\login.component.ts -> src\app\shared\auth.service.ts -> src\app\app.module.ts -> >src\app\login\login.component.ts

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
> src\app\shared\auth.service.ts -> src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\login\login.component.ts -> >src\app\shared\auth.service.ts

Comment: the warning is pretty clear about it, it shows you exactly how the circular dependency is constructed. so what exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't know how to remove this circular dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that the `AppModule` depends on the `AuthService` and the `AuthService` depends on the `AppModule`. You could resolve this issue by moving the `MINUTE` and `HOUR` constants into their own individual file somewhere else in the project.